# How to force the numeric variable type in MySQL to use DECIMAL(23,0) instead of DECIMAL (65,30)?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to use a variable in a MySQL query to get a diff between 2 sums.

This is the simplified version:

```sql
SELECT 
    @foo := SUM(t.data LIKE '%foo%') AS FOO,
    @bar := SUM(t.data LIKE '%bar%') AS BAR,
    @diff := @query - @location AS DIFF
FROM MyTable t GROUP BY groupId
```

The problem I'm having is that the column `DIFF` type is `DECIMAL(270,30)`. This causes an issue when trying to read it as an `int` from an application.

`FOO` and `BAR` are both `DECIMAL(23,0)`.

How can I force `DIFF` to be the same type as `FOO` and `BAR`?

Comment: Have you tried using a `CAST`?

Answer (score 0):

As per @mark-rotteveel suggestion, `CAST` can be used to change the result type.

In this case:

```sql
SELECT 
    @foo := SUM(t.data LIKE '%foo%') AS FOO,
    @bar := SUM(t.data LIKE '%bar%') AS BAR,
    CAST(@query - @location, DECIMAL(23,0)) AS DIFF
FROM MyTable t GROUP BY groupId
```